# How can we sort a table in alphabetical order with permanent to store database in drupal?

Tags: drupal, view

I am developing a drupal view with table format.

I am using default sorting in views.

Its working fine for me,
but here we want when we click refresh button its automatically going to default sorting stage.

I want that it's not take a site default behavior,when we click on sorting it sorting order permanently store in database and show me view also.

any help is great appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the view sorting behavior by changing the view options under sort criteria. Also, if using a table format of the view results, you can, in the table format settings (Format: Table | Settings) set the option what is your "default sort" (there is a radio button option next to every field in the table). Once the page is refreshed, the listing of elements in the view will be sorted by that default sort option.